# P2P communication/LLCP NFC reader-NFC phone

Tags: android, nfc, nexus-s, nfc-p2p

All USB/RS232 NFC readers I am aware of have SDK, which allows programming them in NFC read/write mode, which is usually unusable when it comes to communication with mobile phones, since they mobile phones have to use the card emulation mode, which means use of the secure element, which is either not possible at all or hard.

Do you have any experiences (NFC stack + concrete NFC reader) with programming NFC readers which can communicate with mobile devices with use of the peer2peer communication/LLCP?

Regards,
STeN

Answer (score 1):

I have experimented with (earlier versions of) [nfcpy](http://nfcpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and [ismb-npp-java](http://code.google.com/p/ismb-npp-java/wiki/NppFromACR122ToPhone). 
I know of [nfctools](http://www.grundid.de/nfc/) ([source](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools)), but have no experience with it.

Comment: What was the nfcpy and ismb-npp-java experience? Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: ismb-npp-java worked as claimed. It only does NPP, though, not SNEP, and only at 106kbps, I think. With nfcpy, the experience varied: some minor modifications were necessary to make it find the reader I was using. It worked OK between to readers. It did not have NPP support then, so I could not test it with Android (Nexus S), because Android did not have SNEP support yet.

Comment: ismb-npp-java alternate in SNEP https://github.com/zoonooz/Android-Beam-NFC-NDEF-Push-to-Reader